# Make files in ISO image executable

Tags: permissions

I am creating an ISO image using Brasero on Ubuntu. Some of the files are executable, but as soon as I created the ISO image the files are read-only and with no other attribute. How can I retain the file attributes so they can remain being executable?

Comment: what's the problem to have a read-only executable?

Comment: That's the only attribute all other attributes are lost including execution.

Comment: You probably need to specify Rock Ridge and/or Joliet options to capture permissions (and long file names and other metadata). Plain standard ISO-9660 knows nothing of executable permissions...

Comment: @twalberg, How can I specify those options?

Comment: @zulq I'm not familiar with `brasero`, so I don't know off the top of my head. Check the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

problem is that CD file system doesn't know anything about 'executable' attribute.. you can specify it inside 'mount' command then mounting drive that you want to treat files on CD as being executable.. for example like:

sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/disk0 /mount/cdrom

or anything like that...